# how to give cell indentation level for UITable view in swift 3 ?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am having web services data which I got from model class and how to send the data to the table view cell with indentation level without using external libraries and need to display as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: maybe they are three kinds of cell?

Comment: Take ref from [here](http://sapandiwakar.in/nested-sections-in-uitableview/)

Comment: upto three level I need @xxi

Comment: 1. according your level create different cell. 2. if everything is same except left margin, maybe you can simply set leading constraint? or do some hide/show setting

Comment: how to set tell me clearly I am unable to understand as I am trainee @xxi

Comment: We're not here to be your teacher. Read books, tutorials, Apple documentation, ... and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

I think the means of three kinds of cell won't confused you

so here is second method

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}
```

and in some VC, I think this is a easiest way

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    // let arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
    let order = self.arr[indexPath.row]
    switch order {
    case 1: cell.leftConstraint.constant = 10
    case 2: cell.leftConstraint.constant = 30
    case 3: cell.leftConstraint.constant = 50
    default: break
    }

    cell.theLabel.text = "I'm level\(order)"
    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting a dynamic array that is child array and products array in it will increase or decrease then how it will suits @xxi

Comment: parent will be single but child and products array will increase or decrease and may not be there in some dictionaries at that time it will work or not @xxi

Comment: well....It hard to say HOW, since I don't know how is your array look like, I just demo a simple way. If you think this method may work then you just need to find a way to define your cell level and set constraint as like the code above

Comment: the api for this is http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cwqUAMjKGa?indent=2

Comment: how to pass the array count dynamically in this case @ZHZ

Comment: You can set the indentationLevel of the cell with code like this, cell.indentationLevel = 10